Prime factorization and eigendecomposition
There seems to be an analogy between (a) the role of prime numbers relative to integers and multiplication and (b) the role of eigenpairs relative to vector spaces and matrix multiplication. Wondering if there is some broad theoretical bridge here — if so, what would be some relevant terms for me to read about?
For context, I have no real math training but like to watch from the sidelines and muse to myself.

I’m voting to close this question because it's much too general for a mathematical answer. The situations are analogous, but the analogy does not lead to a useful generalization.
